# Numerically Solving A Multivariate Differential Equation Without odeint

Tags: python, physics, numeric, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am curious. I know this can be solved by using odeint, but I'm trying to do it from scratch, and I've encountered an interesting behaviour.

Assume a simple oscillator, of equation `m * x_ddot + k * x = 0`. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator)

Initial conditions are `x0 != 0`;

Theoretically, the solution is a sine function.

But, on python, the solution is a sine that keeps growing in amplitude. Now I'm curious why that's happening, because it shouldn't. Does it have to do with numerical stability, or something similar? Like, why is it diverging? From a physics point of view, there is no reason it should, so why is it behaving as such?

Here's the code.

```py
dt = 0.05
t_start = 0
t_finish = 20
t = 0
x1 = 1
X1 = []

x2 = 0
X2 = []

while t <= t_finish:    
    
    X1.append(x1)
    X2.append(x2)
    
    # state space representation
    x1_dot = x2
    x2_dot = -9.81*x1
    
    x1 += dt*x1_dot
    x2 += dt*x2_dot
    
    t += dt

# to make sure the vectors are of equal size for plotting
if len(X1) > len(time):
    X1 = X1[:len(X1)-1]
elif len(X1) < len(time):
    time = time[:len(time)-1]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(time,X1)
plt.grid()
```

Here's the plot.

[image: Imgur]

I'm thankful for any insight you guys can offer.

Comment: Apart from being off-topic, probably math.SE, might be too simple for scicomp.SE,... This is the Euler method and this behavior is typical for it. The exact solution are concentric ellipses, the Euler step moves along a tangent which is to the outside of the current ellipse. This increases the amplitude in each step. Any higher-order method will give a much more stable amplitude. You need special (symplectic) methods for a constant amplitude.

Comment: I suspected the Euler method wasn't stable enough. I was just curious why, because I couldn't find any explanation online. In fact, when I used RK4, it gave a much much stable amplitude. The amplitude was still increasing, but at a much slower rate than with Euler. Thank you so much for your comment, it helped a lot.

Comment: What is the significance of `-9.81`?

Comment: @fallen_one did you try to make your step size smaller in euler scheme. This should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is in your understanding of Euler scheme. This is a very simple ODE, in fact its a textbook example for the harmonic oscillation system. The Euler scheme is pretty much based off N = T/(dt) where N is the number of steps, T the final time and dt the step size. So, if your step size or final time is not small relative to the N, the solution drifts up.

There is no need to use RK4, Euler will get the job done. The trick though is that you need a small dt. I have rewritten your scheme in a more clear way and used an appropriate dt respectively.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
t_finish = 20.0
dt = 0.00005 # Very small dt (infinitesmal dt)
n = int(t_finish/dt)

tvalue = np.linspace(0, t_finish, n+1)
x1 = np.zeros(n+1)
x2 = np.zeros(n+1)

# create canvas
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# Initialize
x1[0] = 1.0 # Not at zero
x2[0] = 0.0

# Simulation with Euler scheme
for i in range(n):
        t = (i+1)*dt
        x1[i+1] = x1[i] + x2[i]*dt
        x2[i+1] = x2[i] -9.81*x1[i]*dt
        
# Plot paths
plt.plot(tvalue, x1, label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(tvalue, x2, label=r'$x_2$')

# Add legend and axes labels
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel(r'$t$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x_{t}$')
plt.show()
```

[image]